# git gc doesn't remove .old-pack and .old-idx files in the /objects/pack/preserved/

Tags: git, jgit

I am looking to remove garbage from the git repository. However, the `git gc` command and `jgit` doesn't help to remove more than 2 years old files e.g. `./objects/pack/preserved/<sha>.old-pack` and `./objects/pack/preserved/<sha>.old-idx`.

I have tried using following commands.

```
$ git gc 
$ git gc --auto 
$ git gc --aggressive 
$ jgit --git-dir=`pwd` gc 
$ jgit --git-dir=`pwd` gc --aggressive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files can be removed with jgit using the --prune-preserved option to gc:

https://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=91132bb05e767694d35230d515443d54ddc4eff6